# how to get server cpu and memory and disk percentage in node.js

Tags: javascript, cpu

```
var os  = require('os-utils');
os.cpuUsage(function(v){
    console.log( 'os-utils CPU Usage (%): ' + v ); 
    // os-utils CPU Usage (%): 0.11180382377389864
});
os.cpuFree(function(v){
    console.log( 'os-utils CPU Free:' + v );
    // os-utils CPU Free:0.8876135425268373
});

var osu = require('node-os-utils')
var cpu = osu.cpu
cpu.usage()
.then(info => {
    console.log('node-os-utils cpu.usage '+info)
    // node-os-utils cpu.usage 11.53
})
cpu.free()
.then(info => {
    console.log('node-os-utils cpu.free '+ info)
    // node-os-utils cpu.free 88.47
})
```

it's so annoying.
Why is the os-utils value different from the node-os-utils value?
I need the CPU and disk memory values ​​of the server currently running node.js
-Current CPU usage** (percent)
-Available memory* (free/total)
-Available disk space (free/total)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like `os-utils` package works well. Just format of percentage was given from 0 to 1, meaning `0 => 0%` and `1 => 100%` and so on.

About getting disk space volume info you can use package `diskusage`.
You can check docs there https://www.npmjs.com/package/diskusage

```
const disk = require('diskusage');

// get disk usage. Takes mount point as first parameter
disk.check('/', function(err, info) {
    const freeInPercentage = info.free / info.total;
    const usedInPercentage = info.available / info.total;

    console.log(`free disk space: ${freeInPercentage * 100}%`);
    console.log(`used disk space: ${usedInPercentage * 100}%`);
});
```

Comment: it was a big help. I have another question

Comment: os.cpuUsage(function(v){
    v = Math.round(v*100);
 console.log( `os-utils CPU Usage : ${v}%`);
    return v
});

Comment: I want to put the value of v in a variable and use it as a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is the os-utils value different from the node-os-utils value?

Because one is a percentage (a number between 0 and 100) and one is a number between 0 and 1.

(I would assume that multi-core systems may multiple the maximum number by the number of cores.)

The values are the same. They are just expressed in very slightly different terms.